# How to perceive dynamic android checkbox clicks and save state

Tags: android, checkbox

I have gone through various checkbox related questions but still struggling to find an answer that suits my problem.
I have a normal requirement of checkboxes to be made available to the user to check and uncheck. The 'Layers' checked by the 
user will be visible in the background map and the onces unchecked wont be visible.

My problem is that i am unable to properly maintain the state as to which checkboxes must be checked when the 
dialog box opens every time. Currently, suppose if i check Layer 1 and Layer 5 and set them as visible 
and then i uncheck just Layer 1 later on in order to vanish just 1; both 1 and 5 get vanished. 
I feel it might be due to the global variable i am using to set the boolean. Would be great if anyone could help me. Thanks.

[image: The following is the UI representation]

The layout layer_checkbox.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 

            <TextView
              android:id="@+id/label"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/check"
              android:text="@+id/label"
              android:textSize="20sp"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:textColor="#0d00ff" >
           </TextView>

          <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/check"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
             android:layout_marginRight="10px" 
             >
          </CheckBox>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

The following is my approach:
1. The method initLayerManagementDialog():

```
//These two are global variables.
  public CharSequence[] charSequenceItems;
  public boolean checked1[];

 //This method is called when the Layers option is clicked.
  public void initLayerManagementDialog()
{
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   builder.setTitle("Layers"); 
   AlertDialog dialog;
   charSequenceItems = map.getLayerList().toArray(new   CharSequence[map.getLayerList().size()]);       
    final boolean [] checked = new boolean[charSequenceItems.length];
    checked1 = new boolean[charSequenceItems.length];

   LayerAdapter ladapter = new LayerAdapter(myInstance.mApplicationContext,   map.getLayerList());     
   builder.setAdapter(ladapter,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

   //This is an empty onClick method. Looking for a cleaner way to avoid this.
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        System.out.println("CheckBox button Clicked>>>");           
    }       
   });                 
   builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                 
         for(int i = 0; i < map.getLayerList().size();i++){                     
             map.setLayerVisibility(  map.getLayerByName(map.getLayerList().get(i)).getName(), checked1[i]);
         }                                       
         mapView.invalidate();    

       }
   });     
   builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                            
       }
   });

   dialog=builder.create();
   dialog.show();
   dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
 }
```

2. The custom adapter:

   ```
       public class LayerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
     private Context context;
     private List<String> SymbolList;
     boolean isChecked = false;

     public LayerAdapter(Context pContext, List<String> pSymbolList)
     {
       super(pContext, R.layout.layer_checkbox, pSymbolList); 
       this.context = pContext;
       this.SymbolList = pSymbolList;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
           .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layer_checkbox, parent, false);
       final CheckBox cb  = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.check);
       cb.setChecked(map.getLayerByName(map.getLayerList().get(position)).getVisibility());
       TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
       textView.setText(SymbolList.get(position));  
       final int posit = position;                    
       cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {   
               if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {       
                   checked1[posit] = true;      

               } else {    

                   checked1[posit] = false;
               }   

           }
       });     

       return rowView;
       }
       }
   ```

The layout xml : http://pastebin.com/hKbnTBNG

Comment: When do yo loose the state, when you rotate the phone?

Comment: I loose the state always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be using an Adapter, because the Dialog builder can automatically create a checkbox list for you. You also don't need to use a member variable for the arrays.

```
public void initLayerManagementDialog()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Layers"); 
    final CharSequence[] charSequenceItems = map.getLayerList().toArray(new CharSequence[map.getLayerList().size()]);       
    final boolean [] checkedItems = new boolean[charSequenceItems.length];

    for (int i=0; i<checkedItems.length; i++){
        checkedItems[i] = map.getLayerByName(map.getLayerList().get(i).getVisibility());
    }

    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequenceItems, checkedItems, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                boolean isChecked) {
            checkedItems[indexSelected] = isChecked;
        }
    }); 

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                 
            for(int i = 0; i < map.getLayerList().size();i++){                     
            map.setLayerVisibility(  map.getLayerByName(map.getLayerList().get(i)).getName(), checkedItems[i]);
            }                                       
            mapView.invalidate();    
        }
    });     

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                            
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
}
```

If you're curious why your method didn't work, maybe it's because in your `getView` method you are getting the state directly from the map each time, but you are not updating the map state immediately when the checkboxes are clicked. So if `getView` is called on the view containing a checkbox, it will get reset to the value from before the dialog opened. This would be a problem when you rotate the screen, or if you have enough layers that the list has to be scrolled to see them all.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour04 for your suggestion. I had infact tried out this approach. But the problem was that since there was no
layout needed with your approach, I did not have any flexibility when it came to arranging the checkboxes to the desired location.
(i.e. to the left of the text) can it be possible to have a similar layout as i have mentioned in my diagram using your approach.

Comment: This approach won't allow you to rearrange it. In my personal opinion, it is best to avoid changing around standard UI layouts if your functionality doesn't require it, because it is disorienting for the user. But if you want to use your method, I think your problem is that the String list is not updated as you check and uncheck boxes, so they are losing state. You need to link the checkbox states solely to the boolean array.

Comment: I would add a parameter for a `boolean[]` to your Adapter's constructor so you can  pass in your `checked` array and store a reference to it as a member variable there instead of in the outer class. Initialize the array with the current values from the map before passing it in, as I did above. Then in `getView()`, initialize the checkboxes using the boolean array instead of the String list.

Comment: Yeah, that just what I mean. But I'm not sure if you'll run into trouble getting each list item to behave as expected (touch anywhere on the list item view to toggle the check box). I would get rid of `checked1` and just use `checked` since it doesn't have to be a global variable outside the adapter any more. Same goes for `charSequenceItems`, just declare it from within your init method. And line 45 doesn't need to initialize the boolean[] since your are going to immediately reassign it in the constructor.